# Angular infinite scrolling: reloading page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser

I'll show you a use case with Angular & ng-infinite.
I've scrolled for 2 pages, so I've pages 1, 2 and 3 loaded in my SPA.
The url reflects the page navigation, so page=3.

Now I want to refresh the page: i'd like to have in my page only items of page=3.
The problem is that the browser remembers the previous scroll position of the page reloaded.

So this is what happens: items of page=3 are correctly loaded (OK), browser remember scroll position, it goes to that position (bottom page) and this triggers nginfinite -> ajax call for the page=4 (NOT OK).

If I were on the top of the page before refreshing the page, refreshing the page wouldn't trigger nginfinite.

So it depends from the scroll position of the page before it has been relaoded.
I tried with `window.scroll(0,-500000)` with no success.

Any suggestions?

Comment: are you using ngInifiniteScroll?

Comment: have a look at this https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/documentation.html
specifically `infinite-scroll-distance` attribute

Answer (score 0):

I think it seems like you need some browser persistence to help you out on this one.

When you refresh the page you lose everything you know about the app before the reload and so you cannot make any difference out of normal first time behaviour and undesirable reload behaviour.

Put your current Page number into localStorage and check localStorage when your app start up after reloading.